# Sorting some query result in a very specific way

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

I need to sort the result of this following query, in this specific way:

1) in the first row an `IdItem` with an `IsComplete` value = 0 and also that the same `IdItem` has already a completed task (IsComplete = 1)

2) the rest of the rows order by `IdItem ASC`.

```
--Current Select
    SELECT 
         IdTask,
         IdTaskDetail,
         IdTask,
         IdItem,
         IsComplete,
         RealQty,
         ProposalQty

         from TaskDetail
    where IdTask = 751
     and IsComplete = 0

             ORDER BY (ProposalQty - RealQty)/ProposalQty ASC, IdItem ASC 

--Creating table and values inside

    CREATE TABLE TaskDetail
    (IdTaskDetail int,
    IdTask int,
    IdItem int,
    IsComplete int,
    RealQty int,
    ProposalQty int)

--Values
insert into TaskDetail (IdTaskDetail, IdTask, IdItem, IsComplete, RealQty, ProposalQty)
values (1642, 751, 10820, 0, 0, 12)

insert into TaskDetail (IdTaskDetail, IdTask, IdItem, IsComplete, RealQty, ProposalQty)
values (1641, 751, 9228, 0, 0, 12)

insert into TaskDetail (IdTaskDetail, IdTask, IdItem, IsComplete, RealQty, ProposalQty)
values (1640, 751, 9228, 0, 0, 12)

insert into TaskDetail (IdTaskDetail, IdTask, IdItem, IsComplete, RealQty, ProposalQty)
values (1643, 751, 10820, 1, 12, 12)

--Current table data

IdTask  IdTaskDetail    IdTask  IdItem  IsComplete  RealQty ProposalQty
751            1641        751   9228   0           0       12
751            1640        751   9228   0           0       12
751            1642        751  10820   0           0       12
751            1643        751  10820   1           12      12
```

The desire result should be this(since there is a IsComplete = 1 task with the item 10820):

```
IdTask  IdTaskDetail    IdTask  IdItem  IsComplete  RealQty ProposalQty
751            1642        751  10820   0           0       12
751            1640        751   9228   0           0       12
751            1641        751   9228   0           0       12
```

the last two row colums have the same criteria so doesn't matter the order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to sort some result in a specific way (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962077/i-need-to-sort-some-result-in-a-specific-way-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a correlated subquery to check if a row has a corresponding row with `IsComplete=1`, and order according to that:

```
SELECT   IdTask,
         IdTaskDetail,
         IdTask,
         IdItem,
         IsComplete,
         RealQty,
         ProposalQty
FROM     TaskDetail t
WHERE    IdTask = 751 AND IsComplete = 0
ORDER BY CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                           FROM   TaskDetail o
                           WHERE  o.IdItem = t.IdItem AND
                                  o.IdItem IsComplete = 1) 
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END,
         IdItem
```